# Make ring of vectors "flat" relative to world space

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector, geometry, mesh

I am trying to simulate liquid conformity in a container. The container is a Unity cylinder and so is the liquid. I track current volume and max volume and use them to determine the coordinates of the center of where the surface should be. When the container is tilted, each vertex in the upper ring of the cylinder should maintain it's current local x and z values but have a new local y value that is the same height in the global space as the surface center.

In my closest attempt, the surface is flat relative to the world space but the liquid does not touch the walls of the container.

```
Vector3 v = verts[i];

Vector3 newV = new Vector3(v.x, globalSurfaceCenter.y, v.z);
verts[i] = transform.InverseTransformPoint(newV);
```

(I understand that inversing the point after using v.x and v.z changes them, but if I change them after the fact the surface is no longer flat...)

I have tried many different approaches and I always end up at this same point or a stranger one.

Also, I'm not looking for any fundamentally different approach to the problem. It's important that I alter the vertices of a cylinder.

EDIT

Thank you, everyone, for your feedback. It helped me make progress with this problem but I've reached another roadblock. I made my code more presentable and took some screenshots of some results as well as a graph model to help you visualize what's happening and give variable names to refer to.

In the following images, colored cubes are instantiated and given the coordinates of some of the different vectors I am using to get my results.

[F(red) A(green) B(blue)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vigL7.png)

[H(green) E(blue)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLldk.png)

[Graphed Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lozN.png)

NOTE: when I refer to capital A and B, I'm referring to the Vector3's in my code.

The cylinders in the images have the following rotations (left to right):
(0,0,45) (45,45,0) (45,0,20)

As you can see from image 1, F is correct when only one dimension of rotation is applied. When two or more are applied, the surface is flat, but not oriented correctly.

If I adjust the rotation of the cylinder after generating these results, I can get the orientation of the surface to make sense, but the number are not what you might expect.

For example: cylinder 3 (on the right side), adjusted to have a surface flat to the world space, would need a rotation of about (42.2, 0, 27.8).

Not sure if that's helpful but it is something that increases my confusion.

My code: (refer to graph model for variable names)

```
Vector3 v = verts[iter];

Vector3 D = globalSurfaceCenter;
Vector3 E = transform.TransformPoint(new Vector3(v.x, surfaceHeight, v.z));
Vector3 H = new Vector3(gsc.x, E.y, gsc.z);

float a = Vector3.Distance(H, D);
float b = Vector3.Distance(H, E);
float i = (a / b) * a;

Vector3 A = H - D;
Vector3 B = H - E;
Vector3 F = ((A + B)) + ((A + B) * i);

Instantiate(greenPrefab, transform).transform.position = H;
Instantiate(bluePrefab, transform).transform.position = E;

//Instantiate(redPrefab, transform).transform.position = transform.TransformPoint(F);
//Instantiate(greenPrefab, transform).transform.position = transform.TransformPoint(A);
//Instantiate(bluePrefab, transform).transform.position = transform.TransformPoint(B);
```

Some of the variables in my code and in the graphed model may not be necessary in the end, but my hope is it gives you more to work with.

Bear in mind that I am less than proficient in geometry and math in general. Please use Laymans's terms. Thank you!

And thanks again for taking the time to help me.

Comment: How did you create the cylinder? Did you calculate the vertices yourself?

Comment: I created the container cylinder in the unity editor, attached my LiquidDisplay component to it, instantiated the liquid cylinder from within that component and set it as a child of the container.

Comment: You can try `verts[i] = new Vector3(v.x, 0, v.z);` and rather set the `transform.position = globalSurfaceCenter; transform.rotation = Quaternion.Identity;` however then you would still need to adjust its scale thus that it matches the parents borders again.

Comment: @derHugo transform in this case would refer to the containers transform. The vertices are Vector3's. I just need to have each one maintain it's current local xz and have the local y correspond to the global y of the surface center.

Comment: I thought this liquid cylinder would be a child of the container? It would help to see your full script in order to also be able to reproduce the issue. The position, rotation and scale need to be applied to that child/liquid cylinder ofcourse. If you have also the parent verts you could try and use `Vector3.Project` in order to always project the vert on the according edge of the parent cylinder.

Answer (score 0):

As a first step, we can calculate the normal of the upper cylinder surface in the cylinder's local coordinate system. Given the world transform of your cylinder `transform`, this is simply:

```
localNormal = inverse(transform) * (0, 1, 0, 0)
```

Using this normal and the cylinder height `h`, we can define the plane of the upper cylinder in normal form as

```
dot(localNormal, (x, y, z) - (0, h / 2, 0)) = 0
```

I am assuming that your cylinder is centered around the origin.

Using this, we can calculate the `y`-coordinate for any `x/z` pair as

```
y = h / 2 - (localNormal.x * x + localNormal.z * z) / localNormal.y
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am not great at math and I don't know how to interpret this into code, but it got me thinking about some of what I do know. I made some progress but I'm still having trouble. I updated my post with more information and results. Using what I provided, how would I apply your answer to my code, if your answer is indeed the same after reading my edit? Fyi, I'm using C#.